# Hyperlinking to a site with port 443

Tags: php, html, port

I am having trouble finding a way to hyperlink to https://secure.mysite.net:443

I tried: `<a href="https://secure.mysite.net:443/">HTTPS SSL</a>`

However it simply takes me to https://secure.mysite.net (port 80)

Is there a way to hyperlink ports using PHP, Javascript or HTML?

I've searched almost everywhere for an answer :(

Comment: Downvoters and closevoters: Look at the comments in my answer - there seems to be a real issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However it simply takes me to https://secure.mysite.net (port 80)

Probably not:  443 is the default port for https, so it's not necessary to specify it explicitly, and some browsers will even remove it from the URL (A quick check reveals that at least Chrome does - the others probably do, too.)

If you were on port 80 using https, you'd see `:80` added to the URL.

There probably is no problem.

Comment: :( I could change the port of the site? But it needs to be https

Comment: @King you probably already *are* on https. How do you know you are on port 80?

Comment: Because the page dosen't load. However it does when I add :443

Comment: @King that's really weird. I guess you'd have to find out which port the requests go to. What browser are you trying this in? Have you tried with different browsers?

Comment: FireFox, whatever the latest version is

Comment: @King Strange.  -----

Comment: @King you don't have to mark this as accepted if it didn't solve your problem. You can tick the green mark again to uncheck it. I'll flag this question for migration to Server Fault

Comment: I know that this question is a thousand years old now, but the problem was most likely that there were two different cache entries, one with and and one without the port explicit specified. And the one without the port explicitly specified probably cached a failed load attempt, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

IE, Chrome and Firefox, behave in pretty much the same way when it comes to parsing URI's.

If you specify `href="https://secure.site.com:443"` most browsers will parse this into the DOM as `https://secure.site.com"`. The `443` part is stripped because it is redundant and because the default port for `https` is already and always `443`.

If you do a view-source you get to see what was sent to the browser, the `https://secure.site.com:443` will remain unmolested, however if you inspect the DOM this is parsed from:

`https://secure.site.com:443`

To:

`https://secure.site.com`

However if you specify an port other than `443` combined with `https`, for example:

`https://secure.site.com:409`

Then the port will remain intact and will stay as part of the URL in the live DOM.

You can't specify `http://secure.site.com:443`, well you can but it won't work if it's an SSL/TLS endpoint. This is for a couple of reasons.

1. `https` signals to the browser that it should engage SSL/TLS and encrypt the request before sending to the server. Specifying `https` is the only way to make that happen.
2. It's perfectly legal to specify `http://secure.site.com:443` or any other port for that matter. However if you're expecting to connect using TLS/SSL by specifying `http://secure.site.com:443` instead of `https://secure.site.com:443`, then nothing will happen. The port alone does not turn on SSL/TLS and when the server receives the request it'll just bail out, you need to specify `https` to tell the browser that it needs to use SSL/TLS.

If your server is configured according to normal conventions, i.e. the server listens on port `80` for unsecured traffic and listens on port `443` for SSL/TLS traffic then there is absolutely no need to specify both `https` and port `443` in your URL's. The browser already knows that `https` means "use port `443`" (unless you specified something non-standard, such as `10443`, in which case it'll keep that port number as part of the url in the DOM).

When you say:

> I tried: `<a href="https://secure.mysite.net:443/">HTTPS SSL</a>`
>   However it simply takes me to https://secure.mysite.net (port 80)

Yes, it'll take you to `https://secure.mysite.net`, however that's not port 80, it's port `443`, **`https` means port 443**.